# clearInterval(); not working (variable assigned)

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

So, I've been looking at this for a while now and haven't been able to understand what's up with it. Most people with problems forget to assign a variable to the setInterval and try to clear the function as oppose to the variable but that isn't the case for me.

My code:

Setting the interval (Works fine):

```
if (message.author.id === "266315986100027394") {
    if (cmd === prefix && messageArray.length > 1 && messageArray.length < 3
        && messageArray[1] === "DavidJS") {
        var DavidJSTimer = setInterval(DavidJSFunc, 5000);
        function DavidJSFunc() {
            return message.channel.send("Message");
            //console.log("Works");
        }
    }
}
```

And clearing the interval (Not working):

```
if(cmd === prefix && messageArray.length > 1 && messageArray[1] === "stopDavidJS") {
    clearInterval(DavidJSTimer);
}
```

They're both in the same .js file both they have more code between them that is unrelated.

Thanks to anyone who suggests anything.

Comment: Are you sure `clearInterval(DavidJSTimer)` is firing? AKA is it making it past the if-statement? I feel like a lot of situations like this are because of something simple like that.

Comment: define DavidJSTimer globally (only for test) and check again

Comment: If you'd provide the complete code, probably we could check better the issue. Maybe the `setInterval` reference is not global. Maybe you are not calling correctly the `clearInterval` and so on.

Comment: They not only need to be in the same script, they must be in the same *function*, as that is the scope of the `DavidJSTimer` variable. Quick & dirty solution, declare that variable as a global variable instead of using `var` inside a function.

Comment: What ***is*** the actual value of `messageArray[1]` in each case?

Comment: drop `var`. What happens?

Comment: @Shelby115 it is firing. That was the first thing I tested.

Comment: @CostDeath Try adding `&& DavidJSTimer` to your if-statement and see if it still fires.

Comment: NB: it makes no sense to have `return` at the end of your interval callback function. The return value is ignored.

Comment: What does everyone mean a global variable?

Comment: By global, they mean the *same* variable should be available when you do `clearInterval(DavidJSTimer)`. Are `setInterval` and `clearInterval` code inside the **same `function`** or different functions? Because variables declared with `var` are scoped to the nearest function

Comment: Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript). This question needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: @Shelby115 once I add that it doesn't work

Comment: @adiga I believe they might be different functions (not sure as they are if statements not function statements)

Comment: @CostDeath That means that when `clearInterval(DavidJSTimer)` is called it's not clearing it because `DavidJSTimer` is undefined. You have a scoping issue. Making it a global variable should work, but ultimately, the call to `clearInterval` has to be in the same scope as the declaration of `DavidJSTimer`.

Comment: @MattWay on the first it is DavidJS and the second stopDavidJS

Comment: You are not sure. Is there a `function(){}` wrapped outside of your `if (message.author.id === "266315986100027394") {}` code?

Comment: Ok figured out what making a function global meant, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, cool. I have marked it as a duplicate. You can accept it.